# Combining a solid object Fresnel glow on top of a glass object?

Tags: shaders

Trying to do an effect where i have a simply glass effect but I want it to have the same Fresnel glow of an object that isn't transparent/translucent. The glow i get from a simple principled BSDF mix is ideal, but when i make it a glass object it redoes how the fresnel effect looks. How would I get these effect to combine in that manner? Going for a shader that gives realist looking objects a cartoony glow which ill texturize and animate later. I'm still fairly new at understanding nodes and Blender in general.

[image]

Comment: I'm still seeking an answer for this. I just need a way to overlay these glows on top of my glass object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by *assigning* faces materials in edit mode.

Here's how:

1) Enter edit mode in Blender.

2) Select the top face you want to be able to apply the "purple" shader to.

3) Make sure your material *colors* are already created. You will need at least two separate materials. (One for the top face, and one for the rest of the cube).

4) Go to the materials tab, and select "Assign". This will assign the material to the single face.

5) To prevent the material from being applied to the entire object, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to select inverse.

6) Assign the previous material to those faces the same way you assigned the other material.

Last) View it in render, it should look awesome.

Here's a picture of multiple assigned materials on one object:

[image]

The answer in total, to this question is simple. If you know how to assign materials to individual faces of an object, then you have solved the problem.

Comment: Please consider that such essentials already have been answered: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh). It's one of the frequently asked questions on this site, so if you think this question is a dupe better flag it as such. *But* I think in this case the question is about creating a procedural shader independent of the actual geometry to get a certain effect rather than assigning different shaders to different components of the mesh.

Comment: Thank you, but the effect is not locked to faces. I'm trying to do a fresnel effect on glass where the outer edge facing the camera light up. In my example the square and a few faces just happen to be lit in that manner, but if you look at the rounder objects you see how the effect isn't just the faces.

This is a useful tip for other things though, sadly not for this situation though.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this setup. I'm posting as an answer just so I can post the pic. Try it yourself and let me know if it works. If it doesn't, I'll delete it (Note - the "True Normal" is OPTIONAL - it looks good in some scenarios, not as good in others. Try both.)

[image: GlowFresnel]